# Special Relativity and current in wire

Tags: special-relativity

If I am a stationary observer and the electrons are moving relative to me,then shouldn't its density increase according to special relativity and thereby create an altogether negative net charge.

Answer (score 0):

Increase in density doesn't mean that it creates negative net charge. The charge is preserved.